# Site assets not loading from a subdomain

Tags: themes, redirect

When I visit the site here > http://stammer.in/blog/ it loads perfectly but when I load it from here > http://blog.stammer.in/ no asset is loaded.

I have set up a subdomain which points blog.stammer.in to stammer.in/blog

After researching a bit, I found out that for some reason, blog.stammer.in is not loading the theme related html and I have absolutely no idea why it's happening.

The site and Home url are set to http://stammer.in/blog/.
Changing site url to http://blog.stammer.in does not do anything except it makes http://stammer.in/blog/ render a blank theme page when an Admin is logged in.

[image: Blank Theme template]

It renders fine for a visitor though.

EDIT: The problem is because of W3 Total Cache plugin. Anyone have any idea why it could have happened?

Comment: This is a problem with the theme you are using. On http://blog.stammer.in/ I get the full html, but a different, nonexisting stylesheet. So you should contact the theme developer about this.

Comment: Nah. I changed theme and the problem persists. Also, the theme html isn't included in every case; if you view source and scroll down, you will notice that there is no theme data/html.

Comment: It's because of W3 Total Cache plugin though I still have no idea why it's behaving so weirdly.